# Use "got" or "have got"?

Tags: phrase-usage, present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs, formality

> Could you please tell me if you got some time to read the report?

In this sentence, I have to use *got* or *have got* ? what is the difference between these two w.r.t. the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*HAVE got* is an idiom equivalent to *HAVE*.

> I've got a report to do = *I **have** a report to do*
>   Have you got time to read this? = *Do you **have** time to read this?*

In Standard English (whatever that is), bare *got*, without a form of *HAVE*, is simply the past form of *GET*. It cannot be substituted for *HAVE* or *HAVE got*. Your example would be understood to be asking whether your addressee had *already* read the report.

In US ***vernacular*** English, *have got* is often reduced to bare *got*:

> Can't come over now, I got a report to finish.
>   You got time to read this?

This will pass unnoticed in conversation, but should not be emulated in any but the most casual writing. Your example should be expressed in one of these ways:

> Could you please tell me if you ***have*** some time to read the report?
>   Could you please tell me if you ***have got*** some time to read the report?

By the way, *some time* is unusual here in AmE; we would ordinarily say either bare *time*, or *the time*.

Comment: In my (Midwestern US) experience, "the time" is unusual in American English, but "some time" is pretty common.  It's possible that this phrasing is even more locale-specific than just American vs British English.

Comment: @CarlKevinson "the time" was a common form of the phrase in the US, but is now somewhat antiquated; the way we refer to time has changed.